# Auto fill after double clicking on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this code in html:

```
<input type="email" id="subscribe">
```

and this in javascript:

```
$("#subscribe").on("keyup change", function (e) {
               //do something
            });
```

If I type anything in the textbox, it will be fine and I will catch the event. However, if I double click on the textbox, and choose an email using Chrome autofill for saved emails that comes by default with chrome, the event is not fired.

How do I handle this?

Comment: try using `input` event

Comment: Where is the duplicate question?